# Delay when updating UI content of ModalBottomSheetLayout in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this list of items in a LazyRow, when the user clicks on the edit button of any item, I open a fullscreen ModalBottomSheetLayout so the user can edit the item's data.

When I bind the item's data into the bottom-sheet UI, it is always late, I mean the bottom-sheet fully opens and after one or two seconds, the data is applied to the UI!!

I want the data to bind instantly or before the bottom-sheet becomes fully expanded, this way the user won't notice the delay.

### Code

**MainActivity.kt**

```
   val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
                initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
                skipHalfExpanded = true,
                confirmStateChange = { false })

        ModalBottomSheetLayout(
                sheetState = sheetState,
                sheetContent = {
                    EditBottomSheet(item, sheetState) { editedItem ->
                        
                        // update database and api
                        
                    }
                },
                sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = 30.dp, topStart = 30.dp),
                scrimColor = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f)
            ) {
            
                HomeContent(sheetState)

            }



@Composable
fun HomeContent(sheetState: ModalBottomSheetState){

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()


    ItemsLazyRow { item ->

    // when the edit button is clicked

        scope.launch {
            sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
        }

    }

}
```

**BottomSheet.kt**

```
@OptIn( ExperimentalMaterialApi::class, ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun EditBottomSheet(
    item: DataItem,
    sheetState: ModalBottomSheetState,
    onEdit: (DataItem) -> Unit
) {

    val name = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

    LaunchedEffect(sheetState.isVisible) {
        name.value = TextFieldValue(text = item.name, selection = TextRange(item.name.length))
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
        keyboardController?.hide()
        
        // other data
    }
    
    
    TextInput(name, focusRequester)
    // other composables

}

@Composable
private fun TextInput(
    text: MutableState<TextFieldValue>,
    focusRequester: FocusRequester,
) {

    OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight()
        value = text.value,
        onValueChange = {text.value = it},
        label = { Text( text = "Name", style = subTitleStyle)},
        singleLine = true,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
        textStyle = subTitleStyle
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

LaunchedEffect always runs after a the composition and only when the provided key changes, in your case, `sheetState.isVisible`. Maybe, that value only changes when the sheet is fully visible in the screen (Android site is not clear about its behavior, check https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ModalBottomSheetState#isVisible()).

Also, compose is built to use ViewModels and States, try to put the following line outside of the LaunchedEffect:

```
name.value = TextFieldValue(text = item.name, selection = TextRange(item.name.length))
```

Hope it helps...